# Get Dropped text on a control in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

I am making a text editor in VB.net 2008, and making a drag and drop basket for text, It is a drop basket similar to with today's downloaders  but it will be used to get the droped text. iam using a rihtextbox control with Enable AutoDragAndDrop to get the droped text. its working great with web browsers but when i drag the text from any text editor like MS Word the draged text removed from the MS Word, if there is any other way to get the text in the basket? My code is below

```
Private Sub RichTextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)  Handles RichTextBox1.TextChanged
            frmeditor.New_TAB()
            If Check_rtb() = True Then
                return_rtb.text = RichTextBox1.Text
                RichTextBox1.Text = ""
                If frmeditor.NotifyIcon1.Visible = True Then
                return_rtb.Modified = True
            End If
        End Sub
```

Comment: You can keep text in MS Word, if you drag with the right mouse button and then choose 'copy here'. Since the source program is responsible for this behavior, I doubt that there is anything you can do about that.

Comment: yes i know source program is responsible but some time when we drop text on a control which is have not support of drag and drop, text not doped. and nothing happened with MS Word text also, if there is any similar method for that ? and get the text

Comment: Looks like you are missing a matching `End If` as well, does this compile?

Comment: My code is much complex while making it simpler in SOF editor i missed end if